# Want to edit ListView entry through context menu edit button

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, edit

I am working on my context menu to be able to delete/edit entries from a ListView.  I have the delete function working properly, but I am trying to figure out how to get the data from the listview to the **newRecord.java** class when the user clicks edit instead of delete.

```
@Override  
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {  
        switch(item.getItemId()){  
             case R.id.delete:
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                         position = (int) info.id;
                         db.deleteGasLog(position);
                         updateList();
                         addItemsToList();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                 return true;  
             case R.id.edit:
                 position = (int) info.id;
                 return true;
             case R.id.share:
                 return true;
        }  
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  
   }
```

I know how to get the _id of the row selected, but how do I get the rest of the information and assign it to a variable?  I'd imagine after i do that i would **putExtra** into the newRecord class and then launch that?

Am I thinking about this correctly or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!